# How can I drag and drop canvases within a Vbox to re-order?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm getting up to speed with Flex and I am looking for any example of implementing a drag and drop re-sort within a vbox container. Basically I have a Vbox that contains a number of canvas's that are full width and 35px high. I want to be able to drag and drop them to re-order within the vbox.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks,

b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a mx:List - drag and drop support is already built in and very easy to use - i threw together a sample for you using the dimensions you mentioned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.DragEvent;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var _source:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function init():void{

                var n:int = 10;
                for(var i:int = 0; i < n; i++){ _source.addItem({value:Math.random()}); }

            }

            private function handleReorder(event:DragEvent):void{

                Alert.show("A change was made!");

            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:List dataProvider="{_source}" width="250" height="500" dragMoveEnabled="true" 
             dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" dragDrop="handleReorder(event)">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="35">
                    <mx:Text text="{data.value}" width="100%" height="100%" selectable="false" />
                </mx:Canvas>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:List>

</mx:Application>
```

And there is of course more info here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/List.html

good luck!

Comment: Thanks to all, all comments were helpful. I wound up using a custom itemRenderer within a list to solve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd first check the Flex documentation available online. There's [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_7.html) example. You will have to customize this for your list control's itemeditor. There's another [example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_4.html) which you should take a look at. If you have a problem let us know.

Comment: Thanks - the issue I'm having is that all example are list-based which my vbox is not, or deal only with simple drag  drop. I need to know more about figuring the drop and re-order piece.

Comment: It's the concept of calculating the drop spot and inserting into the vbox at that position - I'm trying to use the dragOver event currently, but calculating the canvas position to figure the spot to drop is my issue.

Comment: If you have multiple canvases, why are you not using a List control? Your job becomes easier.

Comment: Because I don't know and can't find any examples of doing this, this is why I am here in the first place - to find an example or solution to work with.

Comment: List control examples? I've already posted links. See my reply.

Comment: http://blog.flexgeek.in/2007/03/drag-drop-example/ -- this one drops on a canvas, should be close to what you are trying.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but none of the examples show 1) how to calculate the correct drop spot in a vbox of canvases when dragging one or 2) how to create a list of canvases - I have tried this with no success as it seems like a good way to do things if possible.

Comment: i created a list example for you - create a new project and slap that in and you play around with how it works...